# svn move a whole directory and all its contents over an ssh connection

Tags: svn

i use svn and store my repository on a remote linux server, accessible via ssh. whenever i want to work on some code on a new machine i checkout like so:

```
svn checkout svn+ssh://remoteuser@remoteserver/path/to/repo /path/to/localdirname
```

(localdirname does not have to exist before doing the checkout)

however i often run into problems when doing svn move for directories on the local copy, eg to rename directory `a` to `b`

```
svn move localdirname/a/ localdirname/b/
```

this works fine, but if i do the commits in the wrong order afterwards then things end up in a big mess. people always suggest things like `svn cleanup` and `svn update` but i generally cannot get these to work and end up deleting the local copy and checking it out again. so how can i move an entire directory and commit in one go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried this and it works fine:

```
svn move -m "renamed" svn+ssh://remoteuser@remoteserver/path/to/repo/a svn+ssh://remoteuser@remoteserver/path/to/repo/b
# then on the local copy
svn update localdirname/a
svn update localdirname/b
```

`localdirname/a` disappears and `localdirname/b` appears

this effectively moves the directory on the repository, rather than on the local copy.